# transform usual vertical scrollbar to curved on javascript

Tags: javascript, scrollbar

i need to do a **curved scrollbar** from top to bottom of div.
Does anybody knows how to do this? Maybe some jquery plugins

Comment: check http://lokeshchadha.blogspot.in/2012/06/10-jquery-custom-scrollbar-plugins.html and http://www.jqueryrain.com/2012/07/jquery-scrollbar-plugin-examples/ once

Comment: sorry, but i need not straight scrollbar

Comment: Did you find curved scrollbar that fits your needs? If not, can you provide an image of scrollbar you need?

Comment: Sorry for late reply, here is an image of scroll bar [link](http://i60.tinypic.com/2n15hn4.png)